# Find the reason why Spark application has been stopped

Tags: apache-spark

My **Spark** application sometimes stops due to issues like `HDFS failure`, `OutOfMemoryError` or some other issues.

I know we can regularly store the data for the history server, but that may affect the space and performance.

I wish to record only the relevant error messages (not all INFO messages) in the history server.

Is it possible to control which messages will be printed by the history server?

Answer (score 1):

You can set this property

`log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.history=ERROR`

in the log4j.properties file.